# Install CGAL library in visual 2013 using CMake

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2013, cgal

I recently install CGAL but it does't work.
I follow some steps:

1) Install visual 2013 ultimate.

2) Install boost 1_56_0 (successfully, I have tested it on visual)

3) Install Cmake 3.0.2 and CGAL 4.5 .exe and restart the windows

4) Make project CGAL by CMake and it said: configuring done, generating done.

5) I open project and run file .sln but it shows some errors

I do what you said, @user2942203, here what I got:

note: you can zoom your browser to see it clearly.
[image]
[image]

please help me, I hope it doesn't bore you much.

Comment: Does cmake tell you anything about boost?

Comment: No, Cmake told nothing, I follow the instruction here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6trC5zVXzG0  to install boost it's quite different to Boost.org said but it still works.

Answer (score 0):

By default, on Windows, CGAL libraries will want to use the dynamic libraries (.lib/.dll) of Boost, instead of static libraries. The unresolved symbols that you copy-pasted have ""__declspec(dllimport)" in their name, showing that you are using the default.

It might be that you have installed only the static libraries of Boost, and not the dynamic libraries. Two solutions:

1. You can try to toggle the Boolean `CGAL_Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS`, in the advanced configuration of CGAL, in CMake. That will configure CGAL libraries to search for Boost static libraries, instead of dynamic libraries.
2. You can reinstall/recompile Boost libraries, to include dynamic libraries as well.

Comment: I don't know why my boost installation have a trouble, It can not build Boost.Build engine, Does it make some trouble? Although, with that error visual studio can build a project with boost library correctly, I have tested it.

Comment: @user2942203: please tell us if you have a file named `boost_thread-vc120-mt-1_56.lib` (the dynamic library) in your Boost installation, or only a file named `libboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_56.lib` (the static library).

Comment: I have file boost_thread-vc120-mt-1_56.lib and file libboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_56.lib.rsp, also I fix the problem with Boost.Build engine and I marked CGAL_Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS in CMake and press configuring and generating but I still have the same errors.

Comment: Can you please add `-DBOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC` and `-DCGAL_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC` in the compiler flags (in CMake), and rebuild the CGAL.sln? That will display useful debugging messages during the compilation. Then please edit your question to add the output of those messages.

Comment: I added, the problems don't change much.

Comment: @user2942203 During the "compilation" and not during the "link", there should be extract messages, about the auto-linking. Those are the interesting ones. I know that my suggestion about `-DBOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC -DCGAL_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC` will not solve your link issues. I just want to have more information.

Comment: I added -DBOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC and -DCGAL_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC to "Add entry" CMake and mark them, then pressed configuring and generating buttons but when I run .sln, errors I write in the question

Comment: I'm using win8 64bit, I concern about it.

Comment: @user2942203: In CMake, click on the "Advanced", and search for the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS entry. Modify it to add `-DBOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC -DCGAL_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC`. Those two compiler flags are actually flags for the C++ precompiler: it will define two macros: `#define BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC 1` and `#define CGAL_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC 1`, and those two macros will activate some pragmas that will display messages during the compilation, so that one can see which libraries will be linked by the auto-linking feature of Boost and CGAL.

Comment: I got over all of this stuffs buy install win32 and reinstall visual, boost.... I made project of CGAL successfully but when I run "hello world" program I got this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971157/unable-to-start-program-cgal-vc110-mt-gd-4-5-dll . I really feel tired with this library, I respect what it brings to us but it is the most crazy library ever, I need nearly 3 weeks to install it, so crazy.

Comment: I knew you are one of CGAL developers, please help me if you can. Thanks a lot, I don't want to give up.

Comment: @user2942203 So far you have not shown the result of the compilation after having defined `BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC` and `CGAL_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC`. I cannot help you more without that piece of information.

Comment: 2>  all_files.cpp
2>  Linking to lib file: libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2>  Linking to lib file: libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_59.lib

Comment: @AshrafSayied-Ahmad Please ask your own, self-contained, question.